# How should I remove all elements in a DbSet?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

What's the best way to remove all elements in a System.Data.Entity.DbSet, with Entity Framework 4.3?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

```
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete from MyTable");
```

(No kidding.)

The problem is that EF doesn't support any batch commands and the only way to delete all entities in a set using no direct DML would be:

```
foreach (var entity in dbContext.MyEntities)
    dbContext.MyEntities.Remove(entity);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Or maybe a litte bit cheaper to avoid loading full entities:

```
foreach (var id in dbContext.MyEntities.Select(e => e.Id))
{
    var entity = new MyEntity { Id = id };
    dbContext.MyEntities.Attach(entity);
    dbContext.MyEntities.Remove(entity);
}
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

But in both cases you have to load **all** entities or **all** key properties and remove the entities one by one from the set. Moreover when you call `SaveChanges` EF will send n (=number of entities in the set) DELETE statements to the database which also get executed one by one in the DB (in a single transaction).

So, direct SQL is clearly preferable for this purpose as you only need a single DELETE statement.

Comment: Do you need to call `SaveChanges` after `dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`?

Comment: the real problem is how does the DbContext provide access to all its DbSets/Entities ? There is no way of looping over them unless you use reflection. Is this what you had in mind when referring to "MyEntities" ?

Comment: What about `RemoveRange` instead of `Remove`? Would you say, ["that was only introduced in EF 6 and OP asked about EF 4.*"?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21568526/1175496)

Answer (score 79):

Old post but there is a RemoveRange method now:

```
    dbContext.MyEntities.RemoveRange(dbContext.MyEntities);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I'm using this answer because the code is simple and clear. I'm sure there are more efficient ways of doing this, but I'm working with an Azure WebJob that's going to run overnight, so that's not a concern at this point.

Comment: The problem with RemoveRange is, that you still have to query all entities from the DB (or at least the IDs) since this method is just a wrapper around a foreach.

Comment: please add link to documentation!

Answer (score 18):

Here's another way you can do it in code.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void DeleteAll<T>(this DbContext context)
        where T : class
    {
        foreach (var p in context.Set<T>())
        {
            context.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
    }
}
```

To actually call the method and clear the set:

```
myDbContext.DeleteAll<MyPocoClassName>();
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove all elements **without writing any SQL** and only execute a **Single Db Call**

[Entity Framework Extended Library](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) offers a **batch delete** method.

```
context.Users.Delete();
```

Comment: Do you still need to call `context.SaveChanges()` after?...if not, I'd assume the extended library's `Delete()` method is occurring in a separate transaction from any other database changes that have occurred since the last `context.SaveChanges()` call was made?

Answer (score 2):

As the accepted answer only mentions about the method below:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete from MyTable");
```

and rather gives alternatives to it, I've managed to write a method, which you can use to avoid loading all entities, then looping through them and use *ExecuteSqlCommand* instead.

Assuming using unit of work, where context is DbContext:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public void DeleteAll()
{
    ObjectContext objectContext = ( (IObjectContextAdapter)context ).ObjectContext;
    string sql = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>().ToTraceString();
    Regex regex = new Regex( "FROM (?<table>.*) AS" );
    Match match = regex.Match( sql );
    string tableName = match.Groups[ "table" ].Value;

    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( string.Format( "delete from {0}", tableName ) );
}
```

First block of code retrievs the table name needed in **ExecuteSqlCommand** method.

### Usage:

```
using ( var context = new UnitOfWork() )
{
    context.MyRepository.DeleteAll();
}
```

There's **no need** to call

```
context.SaveChanges()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a unit of work and generic repository you may find the following useful

```
public virtual void DeleteWhere(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;
            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }
            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            foreach (var entity in query)
            {
                context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            }
        }
```

Usage:

```
uow.myRepositoryName.DeleteWhere(u => u.RoomId == roomId);
uow.Save();
```

Answer (score -1):

Using repository pattern, where you give the repository the type of the model and it can work on any model type.

```
    public async Task<int> RemoveAllAsync()
    {
        Context.Set<T>().RemoveRange(await Context.Set<T>().ToListAsync());
        return await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```