# How to perform deletion of entities based on a list of ids

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am just starting with linq and entity framework in general and I have a question that may seem naive to all of the advanced users!

I have the following code :

```
var allDocuments = (from i in companyData.IssuedDocuments select i.IssuedDocumentId).ToList<int>();
var deletedDocuments = allDocuments.Except(updatedDocuments);
```

and I need to delete all the entities in companyData that their id is stored in deletedDocuments in a disconnected scenario.

Could you please show me a way to do this in an efficient manner?

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid fetching all the ids by specifying you only want deleted ids like this:

```
var deletedIds = from i in companyData.IssuedDocuments 
                 where !updatedIds.Contains(i.IssuedDocumentId)
                 select i.IssuedDocumentId
```

Now if `companyData.IssuedDocuments` is a `DbSet` you can tell EF to delete them like this:

```
foreach (var id in deletedIds)
{
    var entity = new MyEntity { Id = id };
    companyData.IssuedDocuments.Attach(entity);
    companyData.IssuedDocuments.Remove(entity);
}
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This will issue multiple DELETE statements to the database without fetching the full entities into memory.

If `companyData.IssuedDocuments` is your repository then you could load the full entities instead of just the ids:

```
var deleted = from i in companyData.IssuedDocuments 
              where !updatedIds.Contains(i.IssuedDocumentId)
              select i

foreach (var entity in deleted)
    companyData.IssuedDocuments.Delete(entity);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Again EF issues multiple DELETE statements to the database

If you can upgrade then EF6 has introduced a `RemoveRange` method on the `DbSet` that at you could look at. It may  send a single DELETE statement to the database - I haven't tried it yet.

If performance is still an issue then you have to execute sql.

References:

[RemoveRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.removerange%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

[Deleting an object without retrieving it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/27/tip-9-deleting-an-object-without-retrieving-it.aspx)

[How should I remove all elements in a DbSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448684/how-should-i-remove-all-elements-in-a-dbset)

Answer (score 0):

```
companyData.RemoveAll(x=>deletedDocuments.Contains(x.Id));
```

I suppose the companyData is a IEnumerable type. The type T contains an Id property, which is the Id of the data. Then deletedDocuments contains the ids of all the documents that we want to remove.

One thing that's important and I should note it here is that the deletion of the documents happens in memory and it doesn't execute it in a db. Otherwise you should provide us with the version of entity framework you use and how you access you implelemnt your CRUD operations against your db.

Comment: I use entity framework 5.0 and I use the UoW pattern to access the DB. The code that worked in memory is companyData.IssuedDocuments.RemoveAll(x => deletedDocuments.Contains(x.IssuedDocumentId)); but this does not mark the records for deletion from the DB

Comment: @gnl Since you are using the UoW pattern, there would be a reposiroty class for CRUD operations regarding the companyData type. Right? Could you please provide me this class. In this class, I will see you implement your CRUD operations regarding the companyData entity. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would like to thank you all for your suggestions.

I followed Christos Paisios suggestion but I was getting all kinds of exceptions when I was trying to persist the changes to the DB and the way that I finally managed to solve the issues was by adding the following override in my DbContext class

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var orphanedResponses = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(
        e => (e.State == EntityState.Modified || e.State == EntityState.Added) &&
        e.Entity is IssuedDocument &&
            e.Reference("CompanyData").CurrentValue == null);
    foreach (var orphanedResponse in orphanedResponses)
    {
        IssuedDocuments.Remove(orphanedResponse.Entity as IssuedDocument);
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```