# EF: Delete Multiple Rows using SQL Query Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

How can I delete multiple rows in a single SQL query for Oracle using Entity Framework?

```
"DELETE FROM WOTRANSITION WHERE woiddisplay = @id OR woid = @id" 

Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    "DELETE FROM WOTRANSITION WHERE woiddisplay = @id OR woid = @id",
    new[] { new SqlParameter("@id", id) });
```

Example code above is wrong and will return error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter' to type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter' to type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.... This is full error message @GrantWinney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to connect to Oracle, but you're using an `SqlParameter`.

Use an `OracleParameter` instead:

```
Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    "DELETE FROM DPCMWOTRANSITION WHERE woiddisplay = :id OR woid = :id",
    new[] { new OracleParameter("id", id) });
```

I made a few others changes too, since I don't think the parameter names are quite correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself. Here is the answer:

```
string query = string.Format("DELETE FROM WOTRANSITION WHERE woiddisplay = {0} OR woid = {0}", id);
Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

For more detail, [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448684/how-should-i-remove-all-elements-in-a-dbset)