# DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

i´m using EF6.

After i clear a tabel and i want to add a new entry to that table i get the following error:

*Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded*

The code for deleting the databasetable:

```
 public void ResetStatistics() {
        _lisDatabase.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE Sortedtubes");
        _lisDatabase.sortedtubes.Local.Clear();
 }
```

After that i want to add a new entry to that table with the following code:

```
 Sortedtubes tube = new Sortedtubes();
 tube.Time = time;
 tube.Milliseconds = time.Millisecond.ToString();
 tube.Barcode = barcode;
 tube.Tubetype = tubeType;
 tube.Target = target;
 tube.Materialcode = materialCode;

 try {
        _lisDatabase.sortedtubes.Add(tube);
        _lisDatabase.SaveChanges(); // Error appears here
 } catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex) {
        // maybe do something here?
 }
```

I tryed the sugestions on the EF documentation with no luck:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904

**EDIT**

The problem seems to be the `Clear()` method (`_lisDatabase.sortedtubes.Local.Clear();`). After i execute this method the error appears after the next `SaveChanges()`.

So maybe there is an other way to handle this? I have a GridView in my application witch is bind to the sortedtubes entity and i clear it so that the GridView is also cleared, when i truncat the table.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand : you delete your table and then you try to add value inside the table you deleted ?

Comment: ok delete is the wrong word i clear the table with the sql command "truncate table "

Comment: `_lisDatabase.sortedtubes.Local.Clear()` marks objects for delete. It doesn't just clear the local collection. You better use a new `_lisDatabase` instance.

Comment: Your instance of _lisDatabase is altered when you use "ExecuteSqlCommand". When you try to save your changes, it looks like "someone else" changed the record and your instance is outdated. Aaron's answer should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your problem lies in trying to truncate the table and manually clearing your local version of the `DbSet`. You should just change your EF entities and save them, then those changes are reflected in the database.

This should work:

```
_lisDatabase.SortedTubes.RemoveRange(_lisDatabase.SortedTubes);
_lisDatabase.SortedTubes.Add(new SortedTube());
_lisDatabase.SaveChanges();
```

Alternatively, try this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10450893/5392513

Comment: I get the same error as in title when i try to SaveChanges(). For your solution with RemoveRange and the solution you linked :(

Comment: @cybertronic Not likely. Only other thing I can suggest is to do a `context.SortedTubes.Load();` after your `truncate`.

Comment: If i Load() after truncate that seems to work, but i use the _sortettubes_ entity as source for a Datagrid and i want to clear it also, so i execute the `_lisDatabase.sortedtubes.Local.Clear();` too but after that i get the error again.

Comment: Don't do the `Clear()`. The `Load()` will clear your `DbSet`. You need to rebind the grid.

Comment: Ok i understand but how do i rebind an object?

Comment: If i debug the method the `Load()` command doesn´t load the current data from database. I see the database is empty but the Count property of the entity still includes all values of the entity befor the truncate.

Comment: I got it, however I think I've gone about as far as I can with this.

Comment: Maybe there is an option to update the entity with the current state of the database table?

Answer (score 0):

I suspected that you retrieve the entiries from database with same context by tracking before `Truncate` the table and when you apply the `SaveChanges` the EF is trying to delete already deleted records by `Truncate`. So, usual way to perform it creating a new instance from context and apply actions. It is not good idea to make long database processes with same context. So, in your case if you want to `truncate` table and use the same context to add new entries later you should detach all tracked entries after `truncate` action.

```
public void ResetStatistics()
{
    _lisDatabase.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE Sortedtubes");
    _lisDatabase.sortedtubes.Local.Clear();
    foreach (var entry in _lisDatabase.ChangeTracker.Entries<Sortedtubes>())
    {
        _lisDatabase.Entry(entry).State = EntityState.Detached;
    }
}
```

Also, if it is possible use `.AsNoTracking` in your queries before `Truncate` the table and no need to detach entries manually.

Comment: If i try this, i get the error: "The entity type DbEntityEntry`1 is not part of the model for the current context." in line "_lisDatabase.Entry(entry).State = EntityState.Detached;"

Comment: What is the entity type ? Is it SortedTube ?

Comment: Yes it is **Sortedtubes**

Comment: "Entries<SortedTube>" this snippet should be your entity type.

Comment: `public virtual DbSet<Sortedtubes> sortedtubes { get; set; }` this is my definition of sortedtubes in my LISDatabase class.

Comment: I already corrected the codesnippet when i tryed it in my programm, so the error i get still persists. :(

Comment: I mean that error: The entity type DbEntityEntry`1 is not part of the model for the current context.

Answer (score 0):

So.. finaly i think i got a solution.

My reset method looks like this now:

```
public void ResetStatistics() {
     _lisDatabase.sortedtubes.RemoveRange(_lisDatabase.sortedtubes);
     _lisDatabase.SaveChanges();
}
```

And my add stays the same:

```
_lisDatabase.sortedtubes.Add(tube);
_lisDatabase.SaveChanges();
```

but the "big" change was in my Sortedtubes entity. I changed the type of *Time* from **DateTime** to a normal **String**

from:

```
[Key]
[Column(Order = 1)]
public DateTime? Time { get; set; }
```

to:

```
[StringLength(45)]
public string Time { get; set; }
```

The problem seems to be the Type of the *Time* property of the *Sortedtubes* Entity. But i don`t know why.
If anyone wants to explain me this case?

Thanks to all for your help.